# Determining time and space complexity of a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

```
def foo(n):
    def bar(n):
        if n == 0: 
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + bar (n - 1)
    return n * bar(n)
```

How can I calculate what is the time complexity for the running time of foo in terms of its input n? What about space complexity?

Comment: Fix your indents please.

Comment: @ChristianDean Attempted? :) OP: How many times does it recurse down the stack - that should give you a clue for both space and time complexity.

Comment: @AChampion Hmm, why didn't that work for me :|

Comment: OP made an edit just before I did. Just checked - rolled it back and it was correctly indented (but not code) by the time I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
 return n * bar(n)
      → n * (1 + bar(n - 1))
      → n * (1 + 1 + bar(n - 2))
      → n * (1 + 1 + 1 + bar(n - 3))
      → n * (1 + 1 + 1 + .... <n times> + bar(0))
      → n * n
```

This appears linear in time and memory - `O(n)`.

Comment: why is it not like for bar(),the no of steps is n+1,and for foo() it is n(n+1),so Time:O(n^2)?

Comment: @kiki Wrong. Multiplication is a constant operation. n * n is a single step. Computing the output of bar is, however, linear.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, It is **O(n)** for both runtime and space.

Let me try to explain it with a recurrence relation and derivation.

**For runtime**

```
Base case: T(0) = 1
Recurion : T(n) = T(n-1) + 1  (constant time for addition operation)


T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
     = T(n-2) + 1 + 1
     = T(n-3) + 1 + 1 + 1
     = T(n-4) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
     = T(n-4) + 4*1
     ...
     = T(n-n) + n * 1
     = T(0) + n * 1
     = 1 + n
     = O(n)
```

**For space complexity**

There will be 'n' stack created for all the recursive call.
Hence, O(n) space.

**Note:** The space complexity can be further reduced with a tail recursion implementation.

Hope it helps!